# Can large pizzas be made in a convection oven?

Tags: baking

Can large pizzas be made in a convection oven? I have a large pan, but it is bigger than the rack. If I make pizzas on that pan, will the pizza bake evenly?

Answer (score 2):

I cook a circular pizza on a pan as large as my consumer convection oven can accommodate and the pizza comes out great.

The biggest risk is that the pan must be kept level to prevent the sauce and cheese from sliding down as the pizza cooks.

In my oven, a pan two inches larger in diameter would nearly fit, but then the bent part of the rack makes the back just a little too high and causes the problem.

Comment: You might be able to cheat and put something on the rack first so the pan is lifted up above the bent portion ... but it's possible that it would cause other problems, as it could affect both convective & radiant heat where the pizza is near the wall of the oven.

Comment: @Joe I tried a few things like that, but it just wasnt stable enough. The pizza pan would spin and slide and bounce around way too much with expansion and contraction

Comment: oh well.  Probably still better than the time I tried making a new bracket for electrical element in my oven.  (the metal I used must've been coated with something, as it smoked up horribly)